# Only add space after _filedir bash-completion

Tags: bash-completion

MWE (minimal working example):

```
_testscript_completion()
{
    # shellcheck disable=SC2034
    local cur prev words cword
    source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
    _init_completion -n = || return

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "VAR1= VAR2= VAR3=" -- "$cur") )
    _filedir # also allow all files

    return 0
}

complete -F _testscript_completion testscript
```

This now completes `testscript` with `VAR1=`, `VAR2=`, `VAR3=` and with all files. However, it adds spaces after `VAR1=`, `VAR2=` and `VAR3=`. How can I omit those, but still not modify the _filedir results?

**Note**: Simply adding `-o nospace` will not help, because this will also add `nospace` to the file names, and will cause the cursor to hang/glue after them.

Comment: if your question related to `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`? if not please post a [repro] which does not depend on 3rd party pkg.

Comment: @pynexj I don't get the question. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion is not 3rd party, right? It's part of the official bash-completion package.

Comment: i mean it's 3rd party from bash's perspective. the bash-completion pkg is not installed on my system so it reported error when i tried you example. i can help if it's not a bash-completion pkg specific question.

Comment: OK, thanks, I get it, but the question is about/related to `_filedir`, which is part of the `bash-completion` package.